# How to make content dynamic?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want my header and footer constant for every page. I want to change only the middle content when a user clicks any menu item. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/header.php') ?>
    <?php $Content ?>
    <?php require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/footer.php') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

My menu is:

```
<ul>
  <li>Courses
    <ul>
      <li>Java</li>
      <li>PHP</li>
      <li>C++</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>About Us</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: After re-reading your question, it appears you want to refresh the content, but not the actual page. For that, you'll want to use **[AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**. I'll leave my original answer below in case I understood you correctly the first time.

---

You can use PHP's `include_once`. Just create a `header.php` file, insert your menu, then insert the following code into your page template where you want it to appear:

`<?php include('header.php'); ?>`

Repeat the process for  `footer.php`